# Split one column into two columns in pandas by the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **Given_Col** in which I have 5 different values. I need to create new columns as follows:

Both A and B goes    ---> col1

Neither A nor B goes ---> col1

A goes B doesn't go  ---> col2

A doesn't go B goes  ---> col2

No idea              ---> both if there the value is NaN

```
      Given_Col                    Expexted_Col1              Expexted_Col2    

Both A and B goes                 Both A and B goes               No idea
Neither A nor B goes             Neither A nor B goes             No idea
A goes B doesn't go                    No idea               A goes B doesn't go  
A doesn't go B goes                    No idea               A doesn't go B goes 
A goes B doesn't go                    No idea               A goes B doesn't go
Neither A nor B goes             Neither A nor B goes             No idea 
No idea                                No idea                    No idea 
Both A and B goes                  Both A and B goes              No idea
```

I couldn't think of any solution. What would be the practical way?

**Note** : I considered duplicating existing column and mapping the values maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.assign` with `fillna`:

```
mapper = {'col1': ['Both A and B goes', 'Neither A nor B goes'],
 'col2': ["A goes B doesn't go", "A doesn't go B goes"]}

s = df["Given_Col"]
new_df = df.assign(**{k: s[s.isin(v)] for k, v in mapper.items()}).fillna("No idea")
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
              Given_Col                  col1                 col2
0     Both A and B goes     Both A and B goes              No idea
1  Neither A nor B goes  Neither A nor B goes              No idea
2   A goes B doesn't go               No idea  A goes B doesn't go
3   A doesn't go B goes               No idea  A doesn't go B goes
4   A goes B doesn't go               No idea  A goes B doesn't go
5  Neither A nor B goes  Neither A nor B goes              No idea
6               No idea               No idea              No idea
7     Both A and B goes     Both A and B goes              No idea
```

Comment: Where does mapper come from?

Comment: One step further, can I replace ```Both A and B goes``` as 1, ```Neither A nor B goes``` as -1, ```No idea``` as 0, in the way you do, at once?

Comment: Then you would make a new `mapper` (something like `{"col1": {"Both A and B goes": 1, ...}`), and multiply the boolean array. BTW, it's never a good idea to ask another question in a same post, especially via comment as not only comment section has a limit in providing a proper answer, but also there's never a guarantee that the answerer knows an answer for a next part ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think two conditional column assignments should work.

Each one picks up valid entries for the column based on selection criteria. If you had more than five possibilities, this could be unweildy, but it should work well enough for this case.

```
df['Expexted_Col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Given_Col'] if (x['Given_Col'] == 'Both A and B goes' or x['Given_Col'] == 'Neither A nor B goes') else 'No idea', axis = 1)
df['Expexted_Col2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Given_Col'] if (x['Given_Col'] == "A goes B doesn't go" or x['Given_Col'] == "A doesn't go B goes") else 'No idea', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with few np.where functions:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['Given_Col'] == 'Both A and B goes', 'Both A and B goes', df['col1'])
df['col2'] = np.where(df['Given_Col'] == 'Both A and B goes', 'No idea', df['col1'])
df['col1'] = np.where(df['Given_Col'] == 'Neither A nor B goes', 'Neither A nor B goes', df['col2'])
df['col2'] = np.where(df['Given_Col'] == 'Neither A nor B goes', 'No idea', df['col2'])
```

You can continue from here....